# Few questions about SM baryogenesis

Tags: quantum-anomalies, instantons, baryogenesis

SM provides baryogenesis via leptogenesis due to anomalies and sphaleron processes. I have a few questions on it.

1. How exactly the anomalies in lepton and baryon currents provide convertation of lepton number into baryon one?
2. How to calculate the height of potential barrier (i.e., the energy of sphalerons) which separates vacuums with different topological numbers?